# In what file do we connect react front end folder files with back-end folder files with server.js and mysql database connection?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have front-end folder files with react components and front-end css libraries.

In different folder, I have back-end files with server.js routing with mysql connection.

When I enter inputs on the screen, the inputs are not saved to mysql database.

Questions:

1. In what file, do I connect my front-end with back-end?
2. What statement should I use to connect my front-end with back-end?
3. To start Front-end, I used: npm start and To start Back-end, I used: nodemon server.js.

Question: When I connect front-end and back-end, what file should I open so that the front-end talks with the back-end -> both are starting?

Comment: Your react app should be configured to know the URL of your backend service and make HTTP requests to it. Your backend service should be prepared to receive HTTP requests from the URL of your react app. I don't know what "server.js routing" is.

Comment: If you're going to run the backend and frontend with one command, you should use the same port for both backend and frontend. To do this you can use concurrently module and setup proxy in the package.json, and modify the scripts in package.json. For more detail, please check https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently.

Comment: Maybe dockerization is what you're asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 answer
You can do this a number of ways. I've done this with Serverjs and react in the
following manner.

```
        const express = require('express');
        const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        const cors = require('cors');
        const port = 80085;
        const app = express();
        const token = 'impossiblylongimportanttokenhere';

        let nextId = 7;
```

You'll need to import CORS, a Parser, Express for routing purposes.
Assuming you'll have a login you'll want a  authenticator function. Please note this is just for development.

```
        function authenticator(req, res, next) {
  const { authorization } = req.headers;
  if (authorization === token) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({ error: 'User must be logged in to do that.' });
  }
}
```

You'll probably want to replace that with something more secure once you're don with development.
with *app* as our router express has several CORS methods to get us started likepostget

Here's an example of one if we had an array called friends and if we wanted to find that friend by ID.

```
    app.get('/api/friends/:id', authenticator, (req, res) => {
      const friend = friends.find(f => f.id == req.params.id);

      if (friend) {
        res.status(200).json(friend);
      } else {
        res.status(404).send({ msg: 'Friend not found' });
      }
    });
```

The best part is that express has a method called listen that will start as soon as we hit NPM RUN on a cli that's parked in the same file location as server.js. Make sure to specify a port that your system isn't already using

```
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`server listening on port ${port}`);
    });
```

Question 2
In order to get connect to Server.js on our side you'll want use axios to make a GET/POST etc. call to whatever route you've made in your server.js above in the example it would be

```
    .post('/api/friends', this.state.addFriend)
```

The biggest thing is you'll want multiple terminals running in order to have both the backend and the front end running at the same time. Start with backend first.